# NVCC - host compiler targets unsupported OS

Tags: build, cuda, nvcc, cl

I've been trying to get CUDA working on my PC. I tried clean (re-)installing the latest drivers and CUDA as well as latest Visual Studio 2017 RC Build Tools. My operating system is Windows 10 (64-bit) build 14393.693, GPU is GTX 1060 6GB (Driver version 378.49), CUDA version 8.0.44.

I took a simple demo from one of the NVIDIA blogs and when I try to compile with "nvcc", I get "nvcc fatal: Host compiler targets unsupported OS".
I setup my envrionment by opening a command prompt in the folder with the .cu file, then running "vcvars64" to add the 64-bit cl.exe to my environment variables. I also tried this with "vcvars32" and I get same result.

I can confirm that cl.exe will compile a "HelloWorld" C file.

Comment: I solved it by changing from 19.28.29333 `cl.exe` compiler (VS 2019)  to 19.00.24215.1 (VS 2015) for x86.

Answer (score 7):

Try using a [supported host compiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).

Edit: The question has since come up again and gotten a better answer here: [Using CUDA with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745099/using-cuda-with-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: so I need to use 2015 Build Tools instead?

Comment: Yes, you need to.

Comment: I couldn't find cl.exe in 2015 Build Tools so I tried uninstalling and when I try to reinstall the setup does nothing. I just don't see why cl.exe from 2017 would differ from 2015 as the error message is about the operating system.

Comment: I have the same problem 7 months later. The liked thread does not help me to solve this problem.

Where is the cl.exe (from the 2015 toolchain) located?